# Route media audio to speakereven if headset is connect (UWP)

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-universal, windows-10-mobile

In scenario 2 of this [Audio Creation](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples) uwp project
i noticed it capture audio from microphone and give output to selected output device in real time.
So in this scenario i selected speaker as output device and start record so it start capture audio from microphone and give output to speakers even if my earphones is connected.

as shown in image it route audio to media instead of headphones

so similarly i want to route media, mp3,FM audio to speaker even if headset is connected.

[image: 1st Image]
[image: 2nd Image]

Comment: Looks like people stop using stack overflow, in my all previous questions i found the answer in a day

Answer (score 2):

This is a exception that works thanks to `AudioGraph`. Unfortunately, you cannot apply this in general to override the default behavior of the system.

Comment: But look at this solution

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f50d21bc-61d7-4058-ba6c-4da6c9b90c95/route-media-audio-to-speakereven-if-headset-is-connect-uwp?forum=wpdevelop