# Typing Button Content ON a Text Block (UWP)

Tags: c#, uwp

In My project i have a Text Block

```
<TextBlock Name="MyDisplay" TextAlignment="Center"
           Style="{StaticResource HeaderTextBlockStyle}"/>
```

And Set Of Buttons in a canvas

```
<Canvas Name="ButtonPanel">
                <Button Style="{StaticResource MyButtonStyle}" Content="1" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0"/>
                <Button Style="{StaticResource MyButtonStyle}" Content="2" Canvas.Left="100" Canvas.Top="0"/>
                <Button Style="{StaticResource MyButtonStyle}" Content="3" Canvas.Left="200" Canvas.Top="0"/>
                <Button Style="{StaticResource MyButtonStyle}" Content="4" Canvas.Top="86" Canvas.Left="0"/>
                <Button Style="{StaticResource MyButtonStyle}" Content="5" Canvas.Top="86" Canvas.Left="100"/> </Canvas>
```

I want to write button content in a text block

My code is

```
public DisplayPad()
{
   this.InitializeComponent();
   ButtonPanel.AddHandler(PointerPressedEvent, new PointerEventHandler(ScreenMarkup_PointerPressed), true);

   UpdateDisplay();
}

public void ScreenMarkup_PointerPressed(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   Button button = e.OriginalSource as Button;
   if (button == null)
   return;
   string content = button.Content.ToString();            
   double digit;
   if (double.TryParse(content, out digit))            
   {
      if(content == "1")
      {
         //codes
         MyDisplay.Text = "1";
      }
   }
   UpdateDisplay();
}

    void UpdateDisplay()
    {
        try
        {
            MyDisplay.Foreground = Application.Current.Resources["ApplicationForegroundThemeBrush"] as Brush;
            // Update the display 
            MyDisplay.Text = String.Format("{0:##.##}");                
        }
        catch
        {
            //Exception
        }
    }
```

But this code is not working it is not update number in TextBlock.

But same thing is used in windows phone 8 which was working fine but only difference in code is (Windows phone 8 code)

```
public DisplayPad()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    ButtonPanel.AddHandler(Button.MouseLeftButtonUpEvent, new MouseButtonEventHandler(ScreenMarkupButton_MouseLeftButtonUp), true);

    UpdateDisplay();
}

    public void ScreenMarkupButton_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
       Button button = e.OriginalSource as Button;
       if (button == null)
       return;
       string content = button.Content.ToString();            
       double digit;
       if (double.TryParse(content, out digit))            
       {
          //My Codes
       }
       UpdateDisplay();
    }
```

Comment: MyDisplay.Text = String.Format("{0:##.##}");   
what is the error? in this code what are you passing to print?

Comment: In windows 8 phone , content of button is written in textblock in ##.## format, but in windows 10 uwp same is not working no content of button written on text block because mouseLeftButtonUpEvent is not available in uwp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `OriginalSource` object is not a `Button` but rather the inner `TextBlock` within the `Button`, so you need to change your code to

```
var textBlock = e.OriginalSource as TextBlock;
if (textBlock == null)
    return;
string content = textBlock.Text;
```

Comment: I think he can use `(Button)sender` and get it.

Comment: @lindexi, not really. The `sender` here would be the `Canvas`.

Comment: But it is button content not textblock, becausemouseleftbuttonupevent is not available in uwp so this not working, when i press any bitton nothing happens

Comment: Also suggest me a alternate way to write button content into textblock , i will try your code and then reply again

Comment: Did you even try my code and put a breakpoint at the line `string content = textBlock.Text;` and test? It **works**. I also already explained to you in my answer, there's an **inner** `TextBlock` living inside the `Button`, and it will give you whatever content you defined inside your button.

Comment: And Please review my this question also
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45319804/route-media-audio-to-speakereven-if-headset-is-connect-uwp

And This solution may help You
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f50d21bc-61d7-4058-ba6c-4da6c9b90c95/route-media-audio-to-speakereven-if-headset-is-connect-uwp?forum=wpdevelop